# Find column "header" after finding a cell value and pass the header name to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hoping for some assistance here.
I have a sheet with some example data as shown in the mock table below.  In the code, I am looking up where each date occurs in a defined set of columns in the sheet, and, if the value is found, it copies the whole row to another sheet.

In this instance, if i looked for 5/31/2020, it would copy row 2.  Row 1 are the "headers."  I am looking to see if, when it finds the value, can I find the value of the column header and copy it to another sheet.  So if we were to find 5/31/2020, i would like to copy and paste the header, "3A" in this instance, to another sheet.

Thanks in advance!

So after the last comment, I can use a helper column to pick out what I need.  I am looking for the Column header to end up in the "B" column.  The formula would have A:A as the search values, then search D2:L2 to find a match.  Once that date match is found, it would return the column header, I1:L1.  From there I can copy the column to another sheet.  Hope this may be easier.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMRwU.jpg)

```
Item    |Order |Condition | ID |  RevisionDate| StartDate |1A        |  2A  | 3A
--------|------|----------|----|--------------|-----------|----------|------|-----------
WIdget1 |123   |111       | 1  |  1/1/2020    | 5/1/2020  | 5/4/2020 |  N/A | 5/31/2020
Widget1 |456   |222       | 1  |  2/2/2020    | 5/20/2020 | N/A      |  N/A | 5/5/2020
```

---

```
 Sub ResultsRange()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim NoRows As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim Target1 As Worksheet
    Dim Condition As Worksheet
    Dim DestNoRows As Long
    Dim Column As String


    Set wb = Excel.Workbooks("Main.xls")
    Set Source = wb.Worksheets("Stability")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
    Set Target1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Organized")
    Set Condition = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Conditions")

    'Target.UsedRange.Clear
    'Target1.UsedRange.Clear

    NoRows = Source.Range("A500").End(xlUp).Row
    DestNoRows = 2
For I = 1 To NoRows
    Source.Range("1:1").Copy Target.Range("1:1")

   j = 1

' ------------------Relevant code to copy/paste results 
    For Each d In Condition.Range("A2:A32")
      For Each c In Source.Range("I" & I & ":Y" & I)
          If d = c Then
          If d <> "" Then

           c.EntireRow.Copy Target.Range("A" & DestNoRows)
           Target1.Range("G" & DestNoRows).Value = c.Value


          DestNoRows = DestNoRows + 1
          Exit For
 '------------End of Relevant Code-----------------                                      
              j = j + 1
            End If
            End If
        Next c
      Next d
      Next I
      Target.Columns("A:AZ").Font.Name = "Calibri"
      Target.Columns("A:AZ").AutoFit
      'Call CopyColumns
End Sub
```

Comment: Range.Find should do

Comment: can you provide an example?  My earlier attempt using that failed.

Comment: Is VBA a must? You can actually do this by adding an additional helper column, which store whether copying is needed or not (by an excel formula), and a Pivot Table (on the targeted worksheet). It would be easier.

Comment: I am open to suggestions.

Comment: So after the last comment, I can use a helper column to pick out what I need.  I am looking for the Column header to end up in the "B" column.  The formula would have A:A as the search values, then search D2:L2 to find a match.  Once that date match is found, it would return the column header, I1:L1.  From there I can copy the column to another sheet.  Hope this may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve with additional manipulation